# Recursively remove Windows Read-Only Flag from Files in Folder with Python

Tags: python, file-permissions, readonly-attribute

I wonder if there is a proper way to clear the read-only flag from all files in a Folder recursively.

I know how I can do this with batch [as mentioned in this SU-Question here](https://superuser.com/questions/653951/how-to-remove-read-only-attribute-recursively-on-windows-7?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

So one way I thought of was to use Python's `subprocess` to just call this batch command.

No my question is, is there a way with either `os`, `pathlib` or anything similar to achieve this?

I know, I could do this with `os.chmod` combined with `os.walk` in a loop, but is there a more common way, maybe any kind of a single method call?

Comment: chmod in walk seems to be the only viable option. `shutil` doesn't even have this (in python 3.4, at least)

Comment: That's a fairly narrow use-case. I think it highly unlikely that this is achievable in a single method call.

Comment: @SiHa I don't think it is so uncommon as use case. I came across this already several times over time in different projects.